# How can i prevent my cat from missing my roommate?

Tags: cats, travel

I live along with a roommate and two of us have a cat though the cat is particularlly attached to my roommate. My roommate sometimes goes on trips and the cat goes on top of my roommates bed and starts meowing his lungs out. I want to help my cat feel better so how can i do that? If i can't help him then how can i prevent him from meowing at 2 am?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like your cat is going through separation anxiety when your roommate leaves. To help with that, you want to enrich the cat's environment.

Provide new things to do, to play with, and to go. Make new high perches or boxes, provide new toys, and provide more stimulation to the cat's activity, such as playing with him. You can even get a toy that releases his food as the toy is played with.